# Show a "subset" of a topology is also a topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

My attempt to prove the following is below:

> Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is an open subset of $X$. Show
>   that the collection of all open subsets of $X$ that are contained in $Y$ is a topology on $Y$.

I just want know if my following proof is valid or not:

I'll start with the definition of topology:

> is a topology on X if and only if the following are true:
>   
> (i) X and Ø are elements of .
>   
> (ii)  is closed under finite intersections.
>   
> (iii)  is closed under arbitrary unions.

So I must show that the collection of all open subsets of $X$ that are contained in $Y$ satisfy the above conditions.

(i) $Y$ being an open subset, is given, and the empty set is a subset of any sets.

Lets call, the collection of all open subsets of $X$ that are contained in $Y$, .

(ii) Lets use a RAA argument.  Assume that there does exist an intersection of sets that forms a set that is not in , and lets call that set $I$.  Also by the nature of intersection $I \subset Y$. Finally, if $I$ does exist, that would also make $X$ not a topological space, however we are given that $X$ is a topological space. RAA

(iii) Let us the same basic argument as in (ii).  Assume that there does exist an union of sets that forms a set that is not in , and lets call that set $U$. Also by the nature of unions $U \subset Y$. Finally, if $U$ does exist, that would also make $X$ not a topological space, however we are given that $X$ is a topological space. RAA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s correct but unnecessarily complicated: you don’t need to argue by contradiction. Let me change the notation slightly to make $\mathscr{T}$ the topology on $X$ and $\mathscr{T}_Y=\{U\in\mathscr{T}:U\subseteq Y\}$.

- Clearly $\varnothing\subseteq Y$ and $\varnothing\in\mathscr{T}$, so $\varnothing\in\mathscr{T}_Y$.
- By hypothesis $Y\in\mathscr{T}$, and certainly $Y\subseteq Y$, so $Y\in\mathscr{T}_Y$.
- Suppose that $\varnothing\ne\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{T}_Y$ is finite. $\mathscr{T}_Y\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, so $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\in\mathscr{T}$. There is some $U\in\mathscr{F}$, and $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\subseteq U\subseteq Y$, so $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\in\mathscr{T}_Y$.
- Suppose that $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{T}_Y$. Then $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, so $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\mathscr{T}$. Moreover, $U\subseteq Y$ for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$, so $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\subseteq Y$, and therefore $\mathscr{U}\in\mathscr{T}_Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Y=X intersect Y and T_Y e uals {U intersect Y | U is in T} . 
 This transformation does not change the algebra on the open sets, except making more sets equal to each other.

Another way of looking at it is that the transformation is obviously a continuous surjection. Thus Y is a space.

(these arguments work for arbitrary Y subset of X)